# What is the Object paramter in MethodInfo.Invoke() for?

Tags: c#, reflection, invoke, methodinfo

What is the purpose of the `Object obj` parameter of `MethodInfo.Invoke()`?

The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> The object on which to invoke the method or constructor

I don't understand how you invoke a method *"on"* an object. I thought you just called a method from `Main()` or a class and that's it.

And, am I able to use just any object of any type for this parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the method is `static` you *do* just invoke the method, and in those cases, you pass `null` to that argument of `Invoke`.

For instance methods, you call the method on an instance of the object, not just on "nothing".  The object instance that you would normally be calling the method on is what you pass to `Invoke`.

As an example, if you had:

```
string s = "hi";
var s2 = s.Trim();
```

You could model that in reflection by doing:

```
string s = "hi";
MethodInfo trimMethod = GetTrimMethodInfo();
object s2 = trimMethod.Invoke(s);
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense now.     But if the method dose not modify the object or interact with it, can I just pass any object I want.

Comment: To answer my comment above. I'd  assume that if the Method dose not modify a class or object, then it should just be static.    . Thanks

Comment: @JackBarn if it doesn't need to access the state of an object, it should be static.  A method might need to access the objects state, without modifying it, and would therefore need to be an instance method.

Answer (score 2):

Its the instance of the object that should be used to call the method, for example:

```
private class MyClass
{
    private string _name;
    public MyClass(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_name);
    }
}
```

The if we invoke the method foo like this:

```
Type magicType = typeof (MyClass);

MyClass c1 = new MyClass("1st class");
MyClass c2 = new MyClass("2nd class");

// Get the ItsMagic method and invoke with a parameter value of 100

MethodInfo magicMethod = magicType.GetMethod("Foo");
object magicValue = magicMethod.Invoke(c1, null);   // Output is 1st class
```

If we invoke with c2, we get:

```
object magicValue = magicMethod.Invoke(c2, null);   // Output is 2nd class
```